# What is the difference between the following HQL queries using null in the where clause?

Tags: java, null, hql

What is the difference between following to `HQLs`,

```
1. "from Object where field is null"
2. "from Object where field = null"
```

Which one of these above statements is correct? How to call `null` in `HQL`?

Answer (score 2):

In ANSI SQL, "Null = Null" gives you Null, not true, so if you are trying to select where something is equal to null, in which the answer needs to be "yes, its is null", then you need to use "is null".